# Index by version instead of node with Apache Solr in Drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6, solr

I need to index not by nodes, but by each revision of the node in Apache Solr. Do I use `hook_apachesolr_modify_query`, `hook_apachesolr_update_index`, or neither? Has anyone done this?

Comment: Sorry to wake up an old question but did you finally got a solution for this? I getting into the same problem here! We tried to index old revision content so user can simply check a checkbox in the search form and search in current AND old revision of content. Looking at the code of the module apachesolr, it seems not to be an easy task since the module work only with entity and don't care much about is vid at all, Thx!

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood your question correctly, as with Drupal6, you can index custom fields in apachesolr. See [this Drupal post](http://drupal.org/node/1490800) on custom field indexing or search [Drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org)

For info, `apachesolr_update_index` has/will be deprecated in Drupal7(beta15), so you should probably modify your code to use `apachesolr_index_document_build`

Comment: thanks but that's not what I need - I don't need to add fields to each `node's` `document`, I need to make it so each `revision` has a `document`.